# Editor for Historische Zeitschrift Style wrong output

Tags: biblatex

It seams that there is an error in Historische Zeitschrift Style Package itself (or maybe its just in my case). When book doesn't have an author, just editor there is an white space where it shouldn't be. When I typeset my file this is what I become as an result:

[image]

The problem

It should be like this instead:

> Vgl. Carolinne White (Hrsg.), Gregory of Nazianzus: Autobiographical
>   Poems. Übers. v. Carolline White. Cambridge 1996, S. X

I need to change this so that white space comes before the parentheses not after it. Can someone please help me with this?

Here is my MWE with all my customisations (I deselected them only so that you can see that its not problem with them but with the package itself).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{white1996,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:05:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:07:22 +0000},
    Editor = {Carolinne White},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {Gregory of Nazianzus: Autobiographical Poems},
    Translator = {Carolline White},
    Year = {1996}}
@book{gregorius1862,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {PDF},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-15 15:58:32 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-31 08:01:30 +0000},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {hym. 30},
    Title = {Hymnus 30: Ad Deum},
    Usera = {PG},
    Volume = {37},
    Year = {1862}}
@incollection{gregorius1980,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 20-23},
    Date-Added = {2013-04-25 14:10:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:04 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {110-193},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 21},
    Title = {Oratio 21: In laudem Athanasii},
    Volume = {270},
    Year = {1980}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
% \makeatletter
% \renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
%   \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
%   \global\boolfalse{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
%   \ifciteseen
%     {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
%        {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
%           {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
%           {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
%        {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
%        {\iffieldundef{usera}
%          {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}{\printnames{author}%
%        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
%        \printfield{title}\isdot%
%          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
%           \usebibmacro{in:}%
%           \printfield{usera}%
%           \setunit*{\addspace}%
%           \printfield[default]{volume}}}}%
%      \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}
%
% %
%
% \renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
%   \global\booltrue{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
%   \ifnameundef{labelname}
%     {\printfield{label}}
%     {\printnames{labelname}}%
%   \ifsingletitle
%     {}
%     {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
%      \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
%   \setunit*{\addspace}%<--- CHANGED
%   \printtext{%
%     \bibhyperlink{\thefield{entrykey}:%
%                   \@nameuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
%       \printtext{\bibleftparen}%
%       \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
%       \@nameuse{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}%
%       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
%       \bibstring{page}\addnbspace
%       \@nameuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
%
% \renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
%   \ifundef\@thefnmark
%     {\ifundef\@theenmark % endnotes.sty
%        {\csgdef{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}{%
%           \BibliographyWarning{Missing footnote mark}\textbf{??}}}
%        {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@theenmark}}
%     {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@thefnmark}%
%   \global\cslet{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}\thepage
%   \csxdef{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}
%
% % NO PAGES IN INCOLLECTION FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
% %
% \renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
%   \printfield{chapter}%
%   \newunit}
% \makeatletter
% \renewenvironment{thebibliography}
%      {\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
%   \printfield{chapter}%
%   \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
%   \printfield{pages}%
%   \newunit}}
% \makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{gregorius1980}
\pagebreak
\section{Second section}
\blindtext\footcite[Vgl.][S. ]{white1996}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the package itself there is no problem (except amissing `[` in line 3 of the `cbx` file. No problem with your customisations (I changed latin1 to utf8 encoding, but I doubt it has any effect.

Comment: So when you typeset this MWE you don't get that same result as I do in that picture above?

Comment: Not at all. Maybe some other customisations/packages you didn't show as they didn't seem relevant? With just what you sent, everything's OK. So I suggest (if my hypothesis is true) that you comment out everything else in your preamble, and reintroduce them progressively until the phenomenon happens again, to find out what's responsible for it.

Comment: Is your biblatex up-to-date?

Comment: I do get the problem here as well (with `biblatex 2.9` and a not so recent version of *Historische Zeitschrift*). The problem is on the second, not the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble seems to lie with the use of `\mkbibparens`.

Apparently, one should not use it as a macro, but rather as a wrapper argument (to `\bibstring`, for example; a lot of `biblatex` macros take wrapper commands) to prevent spurious white space (I could not find any official endorsement of this statement, but found quite often that `\mkbibparens` did not do exactly what I wanted when used as a macro):

Just put this in your preamble.

```
\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1\OR\ifandothers{editor}}
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editors}}
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editor}}}
```

The original definition was using `\mkbibparens` as a macro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1\OR\ifandothers{editor}}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibstring{editors}}}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibstring{editor}}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{white1996,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:05:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:07:22 +0000},
    Editor = {Carolinne White},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {Gregory of Nazianzus: Autobiographical Poems},
    Translator = {Carolline White},
    Year = {1996}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1\OR\ifandothers{editor}}
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editors}}
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editor}}}

\begin{document}
Hi\footcite[Vgl.][16]{white1996}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that solved it! And thanks for answering my other questions too. I am submitting my PhD in the next couple of weeks (doing the last revisions) so that is the reason I ask so much here lately.